# Data not persisting/saving into MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to figure out why my data hasn't been saving in MongoDB, despite calling the `.save()` method. I'm aware that this is an asynchronous process, but as you can see below, I set up a callback using `.then()` - which executes without error. The target database has a single empty collection in it, so I was expecting the data to appear there or in a new collection, neither of which happened. Here's the code for my index.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

const router = express.Router();
const Registration = mongoose.model('Registration');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('form', { title: 'Registration Form'});
  });

router.post('/', 
  [body('name')
    .isLength(1)
    .withMessage('Please enter a name.'),

  body('email')
    .isLength(1)
    .withMessage('Please enter an email address.')
  ],
    (req, res) => {
    //console.log(req.body);
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if(errors.isEmpty)
    {
      const registration = new Registration(req.body);
      //registration.markModified('collection_1');
      registration.save()
        .then(() => { res.send('Thank you for your registration!'); })
        .catch(() => { res.send('Sorry! Something went wrong.'); });
    } else {
      // re-renders form with error message
      res.render('form', {
        title: 'Registration form',
        errors: errors.array(),
        data: req.body,
      });
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

Let me know if any other files would be useful. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here's my start.js file.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('./models/Registration');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection
  .on('connected', () => {
    console.log(`Mongoose connection open on ${process.env.DATABASE}`);
  })
  .on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(`Connection error: ${err.message}`);
  });

const app = require('./app');
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Express is running on port ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Comment: How do you connect mongoose to mongodb ? If you use createConnection then you should use the connection model (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

Comment: @Taymer I don't use createConnection, I just updated the post with my start.js file.

Comment: Is your `start.js` file being executed anywhere?

Comment: Is the `mongoose.connection.on('connected')` being triggered? This should basically print *Mongoose connection open on ...*. Mongoose buffers all the requests until the connection is established with the mongodb instance.

Comment: @VictorF Yes, it is, I've double checked.

Comment: @NishantJain Strangely, that statement is printed each time, the only thing that isn't working as expected is the data appearing in the database.